# Setting proper Unity Container configuration for resolving interface-class in decorator pattern

Tags: c#-4.0, interface, asp.net-web-api2, unity-container, decorator

Given below are my different class declarations and how I am trying to setup unity container configuration to get a Interface to Concrete class implementation. The code currently throws either an stackoverflow exception or suggests that a interface cannot be constructed.

Please help me fix, either the class structure or the container configuration.

**CodesController Class -**

```
public class CodesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork;
    private readonly ICodeRepository repository;

    public CodesController(IUnitOfWorkAsync unitOfWork, ICodeRepository codeRepository)
    {
        if (unitOfWork == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");
        }

        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.repository = codeRepository;
    }

//Other class level methods here
}
```

**CodeRepository class -**

```
public class CodeRepository : ICodeRepository
{
    private readonly ICodeRepository codeRepository;

    public CodeRepository(ICodeRepository repository)
    {
        this.codeRepository = repository;
    }

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<Code>> GetCodeAsync(string codeKey)
    { //Some implementation here}
}
```

**ICodeRepository Interface -**

```
public interface ICodeRepository : IRepositoryAsync<Code>
{
    Task<IEnumerable<Code>> GetCodeAsync(string codeKey);
}
```

IRepositoryAsync `Interface -`

```
public interface IRepositoryAsync<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IPersistenceHint
{
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(params object[] keyValues);
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues);
    Task<TEntity> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues);
    Task<TEntity> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues);
}
```

**Unity Container Configuration-**

```
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(
            "test",
            new TransientLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<IDataContextAsync>("test")));

container.RegisterType<ICodeRepository, CodeRepository>();
container.RegisterType<CodesController, CodesController>();
```

With this given configuration and class structure, based on my experimentation with container config, I get following exception -

```
JSON
exceptionMessage=An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'CodesController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
exceptionType=System.InvalidOperationException
innerException
exceptionMessage=Type '<Namespace>.Api.Controllers.CodesController' does not have a default constructor
stackTrace= at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)
at System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
```

Please suggest, if anything is wrong here, so that I can fix the same. Already struggling many days on this.

Comment: please show the exception details

Comment: Added the exception details above in original question. Hope that helps

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109646/how-do-i-use-the-decorator-pattern-with-unity-without-explicitly-specifying-ever) and I especially like the answer with [this article](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Decorator-Unity-Container-Extension.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You're injecting `ICodeRepository` to `CodeRepository`, which probably causes to stackoverflow exception, since it will keep generating `ICodeRepositories`. It will generate a recursive call. Somewhat like this one:

```
public class BaseFoo
{
    public BaseFoo(BaseFoo foo){ }
}

public class Foo : BaseFoo
{
    public Foo() : base(new Foo()) { }
}
```

And regarding the "does not have a default constructor"-exception, have you registered a `DependencyResolver` for Web API? See one of these questions for more detailed information how to do it:

[Using Unity with Web Api 2 gives error does not have a default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097200/using-unity-with-web-api-2-gives-error-does-not-have-a-default-constructor/37108435#37108435)

[Unity.WebApi | Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936675/unity-webapi-make-sure-that-the-controller-has-a-parameterless-public-construc/34991456#34991456)

[ASP.Net MVC 4 Web API controller dosn't work with Unity.WebApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130020/asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-controller-dosnt-work-with-unity-webapi)

As a side note, you shouldn't have to register the `CodesController` in your unity registration.